# Plot a nucleotide chain in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am interested in plotting this sample figure in R. Sample figure was generated in Illustrator.
[image]

Essentially, my data is structured as such:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(FirstPos = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("pos1", 
"pos2"), class = "factor"), SecondPos = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("pos2", "pos3"), class = "factor"), FirstPosseq = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    SecondPosseq = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
    "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), Count = c(10L, 100L, 1L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L)), .Names = c("FirstPos", "SecondPos", "FirstPosseq", 
"SecondPosseq", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

This is a list of positions (original position and partner position). For each row, the "count" column signifies how likely the 2 nucleotides co-occur. I want a way to display that probability and the order (on the x-axis). In the example, I tried varying the line thickness based on the 'Count'.

Looking through the ggplot2 library, I couldn't find figures like this and was hoping to get your advice on potential packages/ways I could use.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need Network Visualization. See [here](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/) and [here](http://kateto.net/network-visualization) as starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `igraph` package. Below is a basic example of how to get started with your data set.

```
# Assign your data to variable 'dat'.
dat = structure(list(FirstPos = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
          .Label = c("pos1", "pos2"), class = "factor"), 
          SecondPos = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
          .Label = c("pos2", "pos3"), class = "factor"), 
          FirstPosseq = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
          .Label = c("A", "C", "T"), class = "factor"), 
          SecondPosseq = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L), 
          .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), 
          Count = c(10L, 100L, 1L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), 
          .Names = c("FirstPos", "SecondPos", "FirstPosseq", 
          "SecondPosseq", "Count"), class = "data.frame", 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(igraph)

# Create unique names/ids for each vertex in the graph.
dat$node1 = paste(dat$FirstPos, dat$FirstPosseq, sep="_")
dat$node2 = paste(dat$SecondPos, dat$SecondPosseq, sep="_")

# Use last two column of data as an edge list matrix, create graph.
g = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(dat[, c(6, 7)]))

# Add edge weights to graph.
E(g)$weight = dat$Count

# Plot using 'layout_as_tree' to control layout.
plot(g, layout=layout_as_tree(g, root=1), edge.width=log10(E(g)$weight + 1) * 5, 
     vertex.size=30, vertex.color="white", edge.color="black", 
     edge.arrow.mode=0L, vertex.label.color="black")
```

[image]